# Load Angular in a framework or attach it to a DOM element

Tags: javascript, angular, aurelia

I have a situation where I have to embed a bundled Angular application and initialize it in another framework. In my case, it is Aurelia, but the question is more general, and a valid answer could be just attaching and starting the Angular app.
So, I have literally pasted this in my template:

```
<template>
  <h1>${message}</h1>
  <p>${value}</p>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="../../lib/third-parties/my-app/polyfills.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="../../lib/third-parties/my-app/scripts.js" defer></script>
  <script src="../../lib/third-parties/my-app/main.js" type="module"></script>
</template>
```

When I inspect the DOM, I see the scripts and the app root element, but the app isn't starting.
I do nothing in my controller of this view.
So basically I'm looking for a snipped where I can launch a bundled app and attach it to the dom element.
Also, I spend some time (and please skip for recommendation) playing around with Angular Element and exporting them to custom elements. Although the concept is super elegant, it is edgy and fragile. I never managed to mimic my whole app behavior with them.